# Are there any added dangers to downloading an image remotely opposed to browser upload?

Tags: php, image, file, file-upload, download

I have an image upload site, and when the users upload an image I check the size, filetype, extension, etc.

I'm now thinking about adding a remote download feature. Are there any other security issues I should think about, or is downloading an image exactly the same as if a user would have uploaded it from their browser?

Is it as simple as setting `$image` to either `$_FILE['image']` or `file_get_contents('http://url/image.ext')` and then doing existing checks?

The only other thing I would need to do that I can think of is checking the file size before attempting to download it.

Comment: You're right about the filesize. This will most likely bypass `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. Do what you can to make sure someone doesn't link you to a 40G zip or something.

Comment: thanks. is there a way to spoof the reported size of a file (reported by the file headers)?

Comment: Not that Im aware of but I'm far from an expert on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decide to allow remote file fetching, you should use streams instead of loading the entire remote file into memory.

Using `fopen` and getting a stream instead of using `file_get_contents` and receiving a string gives you access to the [`stream_is_local` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-is-local.php), which will allow you to skirt the most obvious security holes, e.g.:

```
$maliciousRemoteFetch = '~/.ssh/id_rsa';
$stream = fopen($maliciousRemoteFetch);
if (stream_is_local($stream)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Hey, don't hack me, bro!");
}
```

`stream_is_local` will return false on URLs and data URIs.

Comment: thanks. this kind of thing is what I was worried about. so I can check the file size before using `curl`, then download and write it to my server (using `fopen`) and then do the existing checks?

Comment: You can try to check the size of the remote file with a HEAD request but that's not guaranteed to work.

Comment: How about if I check the `Content-Length` header and stop writing the image once it reaches that number of bytes?

Comment: Right, you can use the `Content-Length` header to verify that an image is within your acceptable size range, but not all `HEAD` requests come with their `Content-Length` specified, so you might have to fall back to a `GET`. Also, keep in mind that servers can set that header to whatever value they want so malicious users might lie.